# How to Replace Multiple Backslashes with Just One Using PHP

Tags: php, regex, backslash

I ran into a situation where I was ending up with strings that had too many backslashes. My search found others saying to use PHP stripslashes() but that didn't do the job because there were more than it would remove. So what is a good working solution?

Edit:

I was working with code that was searching and replacing values in a .sql file over a few iterations. mysql_real_escape_str() was adding a backslash to values every time, so I was ending up with strings like this in the sql file contents:

```
s:10:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value_here\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\";
```

So after all the iterations of search and replace, the sql file contents were unusable because of the additional backslashes.

Comment: What kind of string interpolation are you trying to do? Single or double quote?

Comment: I have fixed your English in the last line.  Please edit your post and show us 

(1) a sample line,  (2) the code you used with stripslashes and (3) its output.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for me is this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\\\\{2,}/', '\\',$strwithtoomanybackslashes);
```

That replaces 2 or more backslashes with just one. And in case the number of backslashes above looks confusing... it's because you have to escape each backslash with a backslash.

The above fixed all strings in the sql file contents, which had too many backslashes.

Converting strings like this:

```
s:10:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value_here\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\";
```

To:

```
s:10:\"value_here\";
```

Comment: It is correct, but `preg_replace("/\\\\{2,}/", "\\\\", $input_lines);` is also correct. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/yrCq5Y).

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace() works well for this

```
preg_replace("/\\{2,}/", "\\", $input_lines);
```

You just need to find all occurrences of 2 or more backslashes and replace them with a single.